# Adding a Spring context to a Jackson generated object

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, spring-boot

I would like to experiment with adding business logic to data objects. Therefor I would like to have Jackson inject the Spring application context automatically to each generated object (generated from JSON).

Is there a way to tell Jackson to add a Spring context to each generated object?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply do this in the constructor of your objects ? So the context would be determined and set as soon as the object is created, then Jackson will call the appropriate setters to set the values read from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [@JacksonInject](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JacksonInject.html) annotation to specify where values should come from the object mapper/reader.

```
@Test
public void inject_global_context_object() throws Exception {
    ContextObject ctx = new ContextObject();
    mapper.setInjectableValues(new InjectableValues.Std()
                               .addValue(ContextObject.class, ctx));
    DataNeedingContext data = mapper.readValue("{\"prop\":\"foo\"}",
                                               DataNeedingContext.class);
    assertThat(data.ctx, sameInstance(ctx));
    assertThat(data.prop, equalTo("foo"));
}

@Test
public void inject_local_context_object() throws Exception {
    ContextObject ctx = new ContextObject();
    DataNeedingContext data = mapper.reader(DataNeedingContext.class)
            .with(new InjectableValues.Std()
                  .addValue(ContextObject.class, ctx))
            .readValue("{\"prop\":\"foo\"}");
    assertThat(data.ctx, sameInstance(ctx));
    assertThat(data.prop, equalTo("foo"));
}

public static class ContextObject {
}

public static class DataNeedingContext {
    private final ContextObject ctx;
    public String prop;

    public DataNeedingContext(@JacksonInject ContextObject ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
}
```